# Destroy observables on unsubscribe

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have the following scenario:
  - an application with a large number of items. (1mil+)
  - on each item at list one observable.

If I create the observables from the application initialization the application will freeze as it requires a lot of processing and memory. The solution is to create them on demand, as items will be rendered in parts at a time. This is fairly easy to do.

What I need is that after I unbind the items, to show a new batch, to destroy the observables that were created and not anymore used.

One solution is that when I switch to the new batch, to iterate through the old batch and destroy. This is also fairly easy to do but unfortunately not enough.

My application is split into components, each one may or may not use items from the main item pool. That means that I cannot just search the previous items that I unbind and just destroy the observables, but I have to search through all components. That is not good from a performance point of view, and also not nice as components should not need to know each other.

So my question is. Is there any way (built in or not) in knockout to destroy an observable, once there are no more subscribers on it ?

Thank you.

Comment: `ko.computed` has to be manually disposed because it creates new references to other observables, but a plain observable should be garbage collected by JS once there are no more references to it.  Am I wrong on that?

Comment: not really. ko.computed have the following 2 options: disposeWhen and disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved in order to dispose of them. Observables basically are attached to the model so unless you specifically delete they will not get collected. My problem though, is that I need to know when to dispose the observables, something like disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved would be absolutely fantastic, but I did not find something similar or a callback to that.

Comment: Is your "create on demand logic" in a single location, or in each component?  If you can put that logic in a single location, couldn't you also then track them and unbind any previous ones?

Comment: Yes, but that was what I wanted to say, I do not want to track it. Even if creating it is easy, destroying it might bring all sorts of problems. I wanted to rely on a "knockout" solution.

Comment: It would help if you add a short code example of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't the [Delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) work in this instance?  if deleting certain properties of an object is what you want to accomplish then using the delete operator should do the trick.

```
var viewModel = { name: ko.observable("me"),` age: "a lot" };
```

and when you're ready to delete a property  (through an event or otherwise)

```
$('element').on('event', function() { delete viewModel.prop; });
```

this is assuming you want to target just one property within the knockout view model object.

Comment: delete works as "method of deleting". The problem is keeping track on what I have to delete. The initial problem was if knockout gives me the possibility to track and not to write the code myself.

Comment: @DumitrescuBogdan i think this is what you're looking for.  [link](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/using-ko-native-pubsub.html)